# Php filter_input_array с массивом $_POST

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться.

Имеются поля формы:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="answer[]['answer']" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]['answer_note']" value="2" />
</form>

//$post = array(answer=>('filter' => ..., 'flag' => ...));
$result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $post);
```

Как для этой формы правильно составить `$post для filter\_input\_array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна валидация и, судя по значениям полей, что они являются корректным целым числом, то можно так:

```
$args = array(
    'answer' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
    )
);
$result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
```

Другие фильтры можно [найти тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.php)